# gspread raise ResponseNotReady

Tags: python, gspread

When i try to use gspread to access google spreadsheet, it always returns "raise ResponseNotReady()", i just follow the user guide in Github, and i'm not familiar with httplib and gspread, could someone tell me how to make it right, thank you for you kind help

the source code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Orait-2018-06-09-200299f40c5e.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
wks = gc.open("sheet1").sheet1
```

the traceback info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gspread\__init__.py", line 38, in authorize
    client.login()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 51, in login
    self.auth.refresh(http)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 545, in refresh
    self._refresh(http)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 749, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 780, in _do_refresh_request
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", line 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1694, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1434, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1390, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1108, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady()
httplib.ResponseNotReady
[Finished in 22.3s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "D:\python\test2.py"]
```